# DeleteAsync fails while Delete suceeds when deleting appRequest

Tags: asynchronous, facebook-c#-sdk, apprequests

I am trying to delete an app request. I have found then when I call DeleteAsync I get an error, while when I call Delete everything works fine.

To be more specific, when I call the following code on the silverlight client side:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(token);
fb.DeleteAsync("/" + appID);
```

I get the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

However when I call on the server side the non-asynchronous code:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(token);
fb.Delete("/" + appID);
```

The app request is successfully deleted.

Has anyone else run into a difference between synchronous and asynchronous code if the Facebook C# sdk?

Comment: I've always use the sync versions and never the async ones.  However, I have seen problems with the HTTP Delete commands from the framework.  Some work, like deleting a comment or like, but don't work when trying to revoke permissions (which works from the Graph API Explorer tool).  I've filed a bug for that.  Maybe what you're experiencing is related.  Their bug tracker is: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Can you mention which version of sdk are you using. and what type of silverlight app - in browser or out of browser app? if it is a bug you can file it at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. Please file an issue on Github. http://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues